# EclipseLink Cache not getting cached

Tags: caching, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

```
@NamedQuery(
            name=DBConstants.SERVICE_BY_ID, query="select s from Service s where s.id= :id",
            hints={
                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value = HintValues.TRUE),
                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE, value = "500")
            })
```

I am using different entity manager on every query request.

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery(DBConstants.SERVICE_BY_ID);
query.setParameter("id", id);
result = (Service) query.getSingleResult();
```

This is always returning data from database but not from Cache.

How I tested -> I changed some column value in database and when I performed the query, the modified value is coming. Ideally it should return stale data since the cache is not refreshed OR invalidated.

***Revision 2:***

If we are trying to cache named queries, then using multitenant aware persistence classes will cause problem. How? Here is the way I think it works:

```
@Cache(
        type=CacheType.SOFT,
        size=6000,
        expiry=600000
)
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(...)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
            name=DBConstants.ALL_SERVICES, query="select s from Service s",
            hints={
                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE, value = HintValues.TRUE),
                    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_SIZE, value = "10")
            })
    })
})

@IdClass(ServicePK.class)
public class Service implements Serializable { ... }
```

Creation of EMF:

```
String tenantID = getTenantID();
properties.put(DBConstants.TENANT_ID_CONTEXT_PROPERTY, tenantID);
properties.put(DBConstants.LINK_SESSION_NAME, "session-" + tenantID);

if(emf == null)
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("<PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME>", properties);
```

Creation of EM:

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

In this case, our named query "ALL_SERVICES" is to search for all services and we want named query cache to cache based on that query. But when we execute this query, EM appends the tenantId to the query i.e.

```
select s from Service s where s.tenantID = <VALUE>
```

This is cached in the isolated cache of the L1 cache and is available till you use the same EM instance.
When you create a new EM instance, it checks if the entry is present in the L2 cache before trying to invoke query on DB. L2 caches only based on the query we mentioned but not with the tenantId appended. This causes cache hit miss and the call always goes to backend.

Now... How do I solve this problem? I can remove multitenant annotations and add tenantId myself in the query. I tested it and it works absolutely fine.

But removing multitenant annotation causes lot of condition checks to be done manually especially when we have dependencies on other persistence classes.

I need a better solution. Can anyone help???

Comment: How are you changing data, and are you getting a different EM context each time?  Check the details in the logs on Finest, as the query cache will only stick around as long as the persistence unit.  When the persistence unit is garbage collected, so is the query cache associated to it.

Comment: @Chris I changed the data by modifying database table associated with the persistence unit. Do I need to use the same EM for all query requests? I am creating new EM using factory for every query request.

Comment: Hi, I tested this locally and it is getting cached properly. However when i run it on my application server by setting the logging level to FINEST, my application server is not logging them at all. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging for how to set DefaultLogger settings if you want to control the logging through EclipseLink on some servers rather then through the servers logging controls.

Comment: Hi Chris, The logging is rectified and I could see. I finally found the issue. It is due to creating different EM every time per request. But it is advised in EclipseLink as well. Don't know the reason. Any idea?

Comment: Different EM, or different EMF?  The cache is tied to the EMF/persistence unit, so if gets closed out and garbage collected, it will remove the cache as well.  Check if you see the underlying session logging in/out between queries.

Comment: Different EM. I am using only one EMF through out. If I use same EM, things are working. Only L1 cache is working. L2 is not.